# What range are L*a*b* values restricted to for a given reference white point?

Tags: matlab, color-space

I've got some images I want to do things in CIE L*a*b* with. What range can I expect the values to be in, given the initial sRGB values are in the range [0,1]?

I get my images like the following:

```
im_rgb = im2double(imread('/my/file/path/image.jpg'));

% ...do some muddling about with im_rgb, keeping range [0,1]

xform = makecform('srgb2lab');
im_lab = applycform(im_rgb, xform);
```

For starters, I'm reasonably sure that L* will be 0-100. However, I found [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/136978), which notes that "... a* and b* are not restricted to lie in the range [-100,100]."

**Edit:**

Matlab's default whitepoint is evaulated by `whitepoint('ICC')`, which returns `0.9642, 1, 0.8249`. I'm using this value, as I'm not sure what else to use.

As I'm always using the same (default) transformation and the input colors are always real colors (as [0,1] for each of R, G, and B), Their equivalent L*a*b* representations are also  real colors. Will these L*a*b* values also be bounded? If so, what are they bounded by, or how can I determine the boundaries?

Comment: The values can be pretty much **anything** as it is dependent on your reference white point.  In MATLAB, I believe the reference point is `D50`.  If you want to see what the dynamic range is, you can iterate through all possible RGB values (2^24), convert each into their L*a*b* counterparts, then find the min and max of all channels.  To start, `L*` definitely lies between `[0,100]`.  As you have said, you need to make sure you **normalize** the RGB values so that the channels lie in the range of `[0,1]` before you do this.

Comment: So this white point thing is a little new to me. I edited the question. After googling a bit, I'm wondering: Would you say that (for a given white point) there's a real shade of yellow that's the most yellow it could possibly be and still exist? Is there a finite representation of this in L*a*b*, presumably with a high b* value?  Is there a theoretical way to determine this, aside from brute forcing it?

Comment: OK, you need to take a look at the CIE Color Gamut: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/CIE1931xy_blank.svg/495px-CIE1931xy_blank.svg.png .  The `x` and `y` co-ordinates are known as **tristimulus** co-ordinates.  In layman's terms, these values are the average normalized sensation experienced for each colour of red, green and blue that is experienced by the eyes.  `x` would roughly be the amount of red, `y` would be the amount of green` and `z` is not pictured here as you can compute this by doing `1 - x - y`.

Comment: For each point in the colour gamut, it gives you a visual representation of what colour is sensed by the human eyes.  The **reference** white point is basically the co-ordinate inside the CIE colour gamut that is used for defining what is **white**.  Depending on the illumination and the surroundings, there are different representations of white.  The most common ones are `D50` and `D65`.  Referencing your question about yellow, yes that's exactly it given that white reference point.  I actually have no idea about a theoretical way for finding the limits (I have never really thought about it).

Comment: As for the finite representation of the particular shade of yellow, my guess would be along the lines of yours.  Find the component that has the highest b* value and read off the L* and a* values.  Bear in mind that I don't have much experience with L*a*b*.  Just enough to know that finding the distance between two colours in this space maps perceptually to how a human perceives colours and that colour distances all depend on the reference white point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically asking how to find the boundary of the sRGB space in LAB, right?

So starting with L*, yes it will be bound between 0 and 100. This is by definition. If you look at the formula for conversion from XYZ to LAB you'll see that `L = 116*(Y/Ywhitepoint)-16`. When you are at sRGB white that Y ratio turns to 1 which makes the equation 116-16 = 100. A similar thing happens as back where the formula basically collapses to `4/29 * 116 -16 = 0.`

Things are a little more complicated with the a and b. Since the XYZ -> LAB conversion is not linear the conversion doesn't make a easily described shape. But the outer surface of the sRGB cube will be become the outer boundary of the LAB space. What this means is you can take the extremes such as  blue primary `sRGB[0, 0, 1]`, convert to LAB and find what should be the furthest extent on the b axis: approximately -108. When you do that for all the corners of the sRGB cube you'll have a good idea about the extent of the sRGB space in LAB.

Most applications (notably Photoshop), clamp the encoding of the a and b channels between -128 and 127. This works fine in practice, but some large RGB spaces like ProPhoto RGB actually extent beyond this. Generally this doesn't have much practical consequence because most of these colors are imaginary, i.e. they sit outside the spectral locus.